# Unable to individually give material to bark and leaves

Tags: sapling-addon

I am using blender 2.79, and in using the sapling gen addon, I am unable to add different materials to both bark and leaves.I'm a total beginner, so it might be an error on my part.Please tell me what is needed.

Answer (score 2):

The Sapling Gen Addon should create two separate objects for the tree and the leaves if you select the leaves and add a material with whatever color you want it should assign that material to the leaves only.

[image]